# Error al importar un componente Bootstrap en Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, slider, nextjs

Error al mostrar un componente de hecho con bootstrap en un proyecto de NextJS pero me notifica un error con **components/ExampleCarouselImage** que no he logrado solucionar.

Este es el error notificado: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0jf.png

Este es el componente ejemplo sin información (Solo agregaba texto e imagenes al slider):

````
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import ExampleCarouselImage from 'components/ExampleCarouselImage';

function UncontrolledExample() {
  return (
    <Carousel>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <ExampleCarouselImage text="First slide" />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <ExampleCarouselImage text="Second slide" />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <ExampleCarouselImage text="Third slide" />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default UncontrolledExample; ```
````

Comment: Suponiendo que configuraste el directorio `src` para la app next.js, verifica que `components/ExampleCarouselImage` este dentro de `src`

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a component does not exists (ExampleCarouselImage), the react example belives you have created that component for image, the easy way, delete that component import (import ExampleCarouselImage from 'components/ExampleCarouselImage';) and the label where is call (ExampleCarouselImage) and replace this label for  and put your image url or dir (sorry the english)

```html
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

function UncontrolledExample() {
    return (
      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
           <img
           className="d-block w-100"
           src="URL IMG OR DIR"
           alt="First slide"
           />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
            <img
           className="d-block w-100"
           src="URL IMG OR DIR"
           alt="Second slide"
           />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
            <img
           className="d-block w-100"
           src="URL IMG OR DIR"
           alt="Third slide"
           />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>
              Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
            </p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
  
  export default UncontrolledExample;
```